# What are the valid css properties that we can use with animeJs to animate css of an element?

Tags: css, reactjs, animejs

I have initiated the the div's border property with 1px and I wanted to animate it to 3px but the border property in animejs method is not working. Is there any documentation for valid css properties for animejs is available ?

**css class**

```css
.data-hierarchy-main-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 21px 38px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

**JS Code**

```js
anime({
  targets: '.data-hierarchy-main-container',
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'linear',
  border: '3px solid #332709',
});
```

Comment: Perhaps try to only animate the `border-width`